# Prevent third party from using my entire namespace

Tags: c++

Although I've searched, I don't know if this is possible at all.

How can I prevent a library user from writing `using namespace myns;` anywhere in his/her code?

Let's say I implemented a library that encloses all its elements in a namespace called `myns`:

```
namespace myns
{
    class MyClass
    {

    };

    class string
    {

    };
}
```

This library will be used by another programmer. How can I force him/her to use

```
// somewhere in code
myns::MyClass myClass;
myns::string myString;
std::string stdString;
```

instead of

```
using namespace myns;

// somewhere in code
MyClass myClass;
string myString; // this would most likely be a mess
string stdString;
```

This would help with namespace collisions.

Comment: The third party programmer will be forced to specify namespace explicitly in case of ambiguity anyway. I.e. your last sample won't compile, unless the programmer prepends `std::` and `myns::` respectively, regardless of `using namespace` declaration.

Comment: I wrote `string` for the sake of example. The point is I want to prevent him from `using namespace`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The standard says one can write `using namespace myns;` to get all the names, and there is nothing you can do about that.

If the user gets collisions after `using namespace XXX;`, that's their own fault. Generally, it is not possible to stop people from shooting themselves in the foot if they try to.

In the end, pulling in all names from some third party namespace is not something that happens on accident, but has been discouraged since about the dawn of time. If the user decides to do it anyways, they better know what they are doing. Really not the problem of the library maintainer.

Comment: Well, yes, that's the point. To enforce a rule that will prevent the lazy programmer wasting time on finding later which symbols are in which namespace.

Comment: @AlexandruIrimiea As I said, you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

One (questionable) workaround I can think of is replacing your namespace with a class or a struct of the same name and turning everything in your namespace into a (static) member of this class.

```
struct myns final
{
    class MyClass
    {

    }

    class string
    {

    }

private:
    // private constructor, copy constructor and assignment operator
    // ...
};
```

This would preclude programmers, using your library from writing `using namespace myns` but... well, like I said, I consider such a workaround to be quite questionable.

Note that users will still be able to use type aliases, such as:

```
using string = myns::string;
```